# Installing Ubuntu on an SBC

Tags: boot, uefi, sbc

I need some help installing Ubuntu. Sadly there are some issues with this board. I can't access the BIOS menu normally. I needed to change the BIOS options in the ROM and flash it. I already disabled Secure Boot and some other things, however I can install Windows without any problems. Access to UEFI is possible. This is the way I flashed the BIOS. I made a bootable USB using Rufus or balenaEtcher. Now to my problem:

With F7 selecting UEFI:USB stick I'm getting this error so quickly I needed to film it and watched it so I could see what was going on:

```
error: file '/boot/' not found
error: can't find command 'grub_platform'
```

But it enters the GNU GRUB menu. If I now want to try install it, the USB stick blinks 3 times showing access then stops and I'm getting a black screen.

I tried to pass some more options with "e" on the grub like `debug=on`. Now I'm getting: `Booting a commandlist`
The USB Stick flashes 3 times and it freezes the same behavior.

How can I debug such an error?

Comment: read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. As it stands, it's unanswerable